# What would cause edit buttons for plugins to disappear?

Tags: plugins, admin

in the plugins page, under each plugins' name usually there are buttons/links like "Deactivate | Edit | Settings". Recently on one of my sites the "Edit" (and "Settings") button has disappeared. I have just "Deactivate" or "Activate | Delete".

My question is - what could cause this?

I am logged in as an administrator, so I should see the buttons. I suspect that something might have vent wrong with the installation of the last plugin but I am not sure.

Is there some scenario when these buttons get disabled (hidden) or do I have a bug / error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit buttons display only when the necessary file permissions are acquired by PHP.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php#L380

`is_writable(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $plugin_file)`

`current_user_can('edit_plugins')` will always return false if the `DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT` flag is set to true (recommended) in the configuration, no matter if you're the administrator or not.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L1118

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It seems that `is_writable` really sees the files as non-writable. I am now checking with the admins...

Comment: @Priednis Check this for further information http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions Also, I highly discourage the use of the editor altogether: http://codeseekah.com/2012/02/19/the-wordpress-plugin-and-theme-editor-must-go/

Comment: Many thanks for your responses. I managed to get the plugin directories writtable and it enabled the Edit links but my plugin is still not working. I'll check the Changing_File_Permissions link and ask another question if needed.  
Regarding the editor - I don't need the editor and I don't use it, it (the missing buttons) was just a sign that something was wrong...

Comment: Does you plugin work though? Can you pastebin it all so we can see if there's something wrong?

Comment: Am a bit [censored] about spending so much time on this, but turns out my server is running PHP4 and the plugin was using __construct() style constructors which are not yet recognized on this version of PHP, so I had to do somehing like  
`function ClassName() {
$this->__construct();
} ` to get it working and now it seems ok...